# Pass updated state of parent to child component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass updated state of `address` in the parent component, to the `center` property of the child component. More specificaly, from the App component to the BaseMap component. However, I can't seem to make it work. Fresh pair of eyes that could help would be appreciated!

This is my code (I deleted the fetch function, it works just fine so it won't bother you. I just need to update the state of my child component):

Parent:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar: '',
      username: 'nickname93',
      realName: '',
      location: '',
      followers: '',
      following: '',
      repos: '',
      address: ''
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox fetchUser={this.fetchUser.bind(this)}/>
        <Card data={this.state} />
        <BaseMap center={this.state.address}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  fetchApi(url) {
    // some fetch functionality
  }

  fetchUser(username) {
    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;

    this.fetchApi(url);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.username}`;

    this.fetchApi(url);
  }

}
```

And the child component:

```
export default class BaseMap extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            center: [24, 56],
            zoom: 11
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Col md={10} mdPull={1}>
                <div className="map">
                    <GoogleMap
                    bootstrapURLKeys={'AIzaSyBhzwgQ3EfoIRYT70fbjrWASQVwO63MKu4'}
                    center={this.state.center}
                    zoom={this.props.zoom}>
                    </GoogleMap>
                </div>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value **is being passed** from the parent component `App` to your child component `BaseMap`.

You can simply access or use the properties (also known as `props`) passed to the child component from parent by using `this.props.center` instead of `this.state.center`.

```
export default class BaseMap extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        center: [24, 56],
        zoom: 11
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <Col md={10} mdPull={1}>
            <div className="map">
                <GoogleMap
                bootstrapURLKeys={'AIzaSyBhzwgQ3EfoIRYT70fbjrWASQVwO63MKu4'}

                center={this.state.center} // this is [24,56]

                centerFromParentComponent = {this.props.center} // this is the property passed from parent component

                zoom={this.props.zoom}>
                </GoogleMap>
            </div>
        </Col>
    );
}
```

}

Using `this.props` you can access any properties (such as states, variable or methods) that you are passing from your parent component.

You might also want to have a look at [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) method. You might be in need it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this.props.center` instead of `this.state.center` if you want `BaseMap` receive state update from the parent `App`. It seems you want to set default value for the `center` prop. Here is [the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-prop-types-and-default-props) to declare a default prop.